# lightning:container performance/security and why no alternative in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, security, security-review, lightning-container

Is there any specific reason as to why salesforce has not provided the equivalent of `lightning:container` in LWC ?

Since `lightning:container` places the component in an iFrame, is it good to use it (in terms of performance and security) for big commercial ISV projects using React/Angular as UI frameworks ?

Comment: What benefit are you looking for here? LWC is massively more performant compared with Aura and supports the idea of a DOM fragment that is managed by a third party framework.

Comment: I need to use data visualization d3.js, so how can i use it with lwc ? i see in Aura cmp there is a way to connect using lightning:container but none in lwc.

Comment: There is an example for using third party libraries and LWC that [happens to demo with D3](https://lwc.dev/guide/javascript_third_party_library).

Comment: thanks for the link, will look into it